# Selfs contents name macro

Tags: macros

Can i make a macro in a class file that take a string like argument and call a local macro? I want to make the following:

```
\newcommand{\somename}{\def\@somename{#1}}

\newcommand{\warning}[1]
    { \ifthenelse
          {\isundefined{\@#1}}
          {You have to define #1. Use this macro: \textbackslash#1}
          {}
    }
\AtBeginDocument {\warning{somename}}
```

Then, if in the document file i didnt define `\@somename` i will have a warning saying that to me.

Any ideas?

Comment: `\csname @#1\endcsname`

Comment: Welcome! Are we in a package or class file? What should the definition of the new macro be? Please provide a complete minimal working example (code for a small document) which shows us how you'd like to use these macros - how will `\@date` then be used, for example?

Comment: Why not using `\makeatletter\newcommand{\warning}[1]{\@ifundefined{@#1}{Booo!!!}{Yay!!!}}\makeatother`? That's what `\@ifundefined` is made for...

Comment: Define/initialize `\@somename`  as the warning and do the redefinition with `\somename` to have the real string instead of the former warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The LaTeX kernel already provides this:

```
\makeatletter % not in a class or package file
\newcommand{\warning}[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{@#1}
    {You have to define '#1'. Use this macro: \texttt{\symbol{`\\}#1}}
    {}%
}

\newcommand{\somename}[1]{\def\@somename{#1}}
\makeatother % not in a class or package file

\AtBeginDocument{\warning{somename}}
```

Note that the first argument to `\@ifundefined` should be a string of characters representing the macro *name* (no initial backslash).

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `etoolbox` pacakge:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand*{\DefinePerson}[1]{\csdef{#1}{}}
\newcommand*{\Warning}[1]{%
    \ifcsdef{#1}{}{%
        You have to define #1. Use the macro {\ttfamily\string\DefinePerson}.%
    }%
}%

\DefinePerson{Steve Jobs}
\DefinePerson{Bill Gates}

\AtBeginDocument{%
    \Warning{Steve Jobs}%
    \Warning{Warren Buffet}%
}%

\begin{document}
\par
Hi there
\end{document}
```